# Inline Anchor Not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am not familiar with [Inline Anchor styles(link)](http://tympanus.net/Development/InlineAnchorStyles/), how can we make it works to show fashion? Javascript/JQuery coding or missing something?

```
[ http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dPMNVE ]
```

To hover **"smells"** *for example* in this paragraph below:

> Inside Vardö harbour walls, then, to a mooring we came, and the **smells** of the place closed round us and took possession. Bobbling about on the **harbour** swell around us were some two hundred vessels of strange **Northern** rig, and almost all connected with the trade in fish.

I would appreciate with your guide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First download the project from this [link](https://github.com/codrops/InlineAnchorStyles/archive/master.zip)

then add reference to the css styles to you head section and use the built in css classes like this :

```
<html>
<head>
<head>
        <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,100,300,500,800" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/normalize.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/demo.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/component.css">
        <!--[if IE]>
        <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->
    </head>
</head>

<body>
<div class="container">
<section class="link-flip">
                <p>The few tins of <a href="#">provisions</a> we did take were mainly to serve as luxuries. For instance, we had quite a large <a href="#">supply</a> of foie gras and larks in aspic.</p>
                <p>I had a vivid recollection of how the last tin of that <a href="#">pâté de foie gras</a> went.</p>
            </section>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

You can copy only the css classes you need from this library and then use them like this [fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/saikotju/eqeokfka/1/)

Comment: Thank you for your explanation, I already put CSS files under head section and put CSS classes separately. I will follow your example to see if it is working.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<div class="hoverlinks">Inside Vardö harbour walls, then, to a mooring we came, and the <a href="#">smells</a> of the place closed round us and took possession. Bobbling about on the harbour swell around us were some two hundred vessels of strange Northern rig, and almost all connected with the trade in fish.</div>

    <style>
    .hoverlinks a {
        border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(52,73,94,0.4);
        font-weight: 500;
        -webkit-transition: background-color 0.3s, border-color 0.3s;
        transition: background-color 0.3s, border-color 0.3s;
    }

    .hoverlinks a:hover,
    .hoverlinks a:focus {
        border-color: rgba(52,73,94,0);
        background-color: rgba(52,73,94,0.1);
    }
    </style>
```

May be of some help.

Comment: Hmmm I see, I thought I did similarly this way. I will test again.